# ¿Cómo guardar datos en dos tablas al mismo tiempo?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Tengo una tabla que se llama centros, esta tabla contiene los siguientes datos

id|nombre|direccion|tipo

Tengo una segunda tabla TelefonosCentros que contiene lo siguiente:

id|tipo|telefono|centro_id

Esta tabla se relaciona con la de centros por que un centro puede  tener mas  de un numero telefonico lo que me gustaria saber es como puedo hacer que al enviar el  formulario se pueda guardar al mismo tiempo ambas tablas

el campo de telefono  es el siguiente:

```
<div class="input_p__contenedor bloque--mitad js--telefono-num">
                                <?= $this->Form->control('TelefonosCentros.0.telefono', [
                                    'class' => 'input_p__field',
                                    'id' => 'form__telefono',
                                    'data-tipo' => 'tel',
                                    'label' =>'Teléfono',
                                    'placeholder' => 'Teléfono',
                                    'templates' => [
                                        'formGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}'
                                    ]
                                ]) ?>
                            </div>
```

La relacion en el modelo de telefonoscentros es la siguiente:

```
$this->belongsTo('Centers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'center_id',
        ]);
```

No encuentro la forma de que guarde en ambas tablas.

Comment: ¿Tienes el código del controlador?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí abajo te muestro como inserto datos en un controlador, a la hora del save le digo en que tabla debe insertar los datos:

```
public function admin_table() {

        $this->layout = 'admin';//cargo el layout de la sesion de administración

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
//inicio validaciones
            $contador = $this->Client->find('count', array(

                'conditions' => array('email' => $this->request->data('Client')['email'])));

            if ($contador == 0) {
//fin validaciones
                if ($this->Client->save($this->request->data('Client'))) {//Inserto en la tabla `Client` lo que contiene en arreglo `data` en el valor `Cliente`

                    $this->loadModel('User');//Cargo el modelo `User`
//Creo un arreglo con los datos que necesito
                    $data = array('username' => $this->request->data('Client')['email'], 'rol' => 'client', 'created' => date("j") . "/" . date("n") . "/" . date("Y"));
//Creo un nuevo registro en `User`
                    $this->User->create();
//Inserto en la tabla `User` lo que contiene en arreglo `$data` 
                    $this->User->save($data);

                    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'clients', 'action' => 'table', 'admin' => true));

                }

            }

        }

        $this->set('clientes', $this->Client->find('all'));

    }
```

Todo lo hago por medio de un ajax:

```
var parametros = {Client: {}, User: {}, Need: {}};//Creo el arreglo con los campos con el mismo nombre de las tablas que modificare en la BD

            if (Id.trim().replace(" ", "") !== "") {

                parametros.Client['id'] = Id;//guardo info en `Id` de la tabla `Client`

                if (Empresa.trim().replace(" ", "") !== "") {

                    parametros.Client['company'] = Empresa;//guardo info en `company` de la tabla `Client`

                    parametros.Need['client'] = Empresa;//guardo info en `Client` de la tabla `Need`

                }

                if (Contacto.trim().replace(" ", "") !== "") {

                    parametros.Client['contact'] = Contacto;

                }

                if (Direccion.trim().replace(" ", "") !== "") {

                    parametros.Client['address'] = Direccion;

                }

                if (Correo.trim().replace(" ", "") !== "") {

                    parametros.Client['email'] = Correo;

                    parametros.User['username'] = Correo;

                }

                if (Telefono.trim().replace(" ", "") !== "") {

                    parametros.Client['phone'] = Telefono;

                }

                if (Disponibilidad.trim().replace(" ", "") !== "") {

                    parametros.Client['availability'] = Disponibilidad;

                }

                $.ajax({

                    url: '/Desarrollo/admin/clients/editable/Editar', //esta es la url del controller, clientsController.php y el metodo es admin_editable, con le parametro Editar

                    data: parametros,

                    type: 'post',

                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (response) {

                        location.reload();

                    },

                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        console.log(jqXHR);

                    }

                });

            }
```

Aquí va otro ejemplo en el que modifico multiples tablas

```
public function admin_editable($tipo) {

        $this->layout = false;

        $this->autoRender = false;

        $response = array('error' => true);

        switch ($tipo) {

            case "Editar":

                if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                    $contador = $this->Client->find('count', array(

                        'conditions' => array('id' => $this->request->data('Client')['id'])));

                    if ($contador > 0) {

                        $Cliente = $this->Client->find('all', array(

                            'fields' => array('email', 'company'),

                            'conditions' => array('id' => $this->request->data('Client')['id'])));

                        $Correo = $Cliente[0]["Client"]["email"];

                        $Empresa = $Cliente[0]["Client"]["company"];

                        $this->Client->id = $this->request->data('Client')['id'];

                        if ($this->Client->save($this->request->data('Client'))) {

                            $this->loadModel('User');

                            $contador = $this->User->find('count', array(

                                'conditions' => array('username' => $Correo)));

                            if ($contador > 0) {

                                $Usuario = $this->User->find('all', array(

                                    'fields' => array('id'),

                                    'conditions' => array('username' => $Correo)));

                                $Identificacion = $Usuario[0]["User"]["id"];

                                $this->User->id = $Identificacion;

                                $this->User->saveField('username', $this->request->data('User')['username']);

                                $this->loadModel('Need');

                                $contador = $this->Need->find('count', array(

                                    'conditions' => array('client' => $Empresa)));

                                if ($contador > 0) {

                                    $Necesidad = $this->Need->find('all', array(

                                        'fields' => array('id'),

                                        'conditions' => array('client' => $Empresa)));

                                    for ($i = 0; $i < $contador; $i++) {

                                        $Identificacion = $Necesidad[$i]["Need"]["id"];

                                        $this->Need->id = $Identificacion;

                                        $this->Need->saveField('client', $this->request->data('Need')['client']);

                                    }

                                    $response = array('error' => false);

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
```